# Finding the right way to sync on Android 2.2

Tags: android, rest, synchronization

I have a private online ticket system that has a RESTful interface to get a list of tickets, view their details and mark them as accepted, completed and invalid.

Now I want this app to be accessible from a very simple Android application, providing basically the same functionality as my web app, just with a leaner interface.

The problem that I stumbled upon as a novice Android developer was that I have no idea which of the many ways to go for synchronization of the tickets.
The target of my application are Android 2.2+ based systems so there is at least AbstractSyncAdapter which wasn't clear to me how to use from the documentation.

Another possibility that came to my mind was simply setting up a scheduled task that would do the synchronisation at specific intervals.

Another problem is that I don't really understand how to use ContentProviders and how to specify custom content types (such as my ticket). Do I need these at all if I merely want to use my data from my own application?

What would be ideal is a reference to a decent open source project that has implemented something like this already.
Apart from that any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Sample Sync Adaptor](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html).

Comment: This won't work well without some sort of Batch operations, which REST doesn't provide.  Also, this requires a content provider and an established User Account (Settings -> Accounts), which is not really realistic for all applications.